# How to block a service (xrdp) from using a specific port?

Tags: iptables, vnc, netstat, port, xrdp

I'm admin for some devs and they requested that a port on a machine be clear for a specific purpose. When one of the devs went to use that port, it was in use. An `netstat -p` showed that xrdp/Xnvc was using it. I tried to have the user jump off and back on to see if it would use another port, but it kept using that one.

From my reading, Xrdp chooses random, open port. I can figure out how to blacklist that port from the service.

The system: CentOS 7, using iptables instead of firewalld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TCP/IP, there is no such thing as "an open port that is not used by anything". Any port that is not currently being used is going to be closed. In addition to that, iptables or any firewall can *block* certain ports from some or all traffic.

(I really hate the talk of "opening a port" in firewalls, because it feeds a misconception on how TCP and UDP ports work. A port can be *unblocked* in a firewall, but then you actually need some program or kernel-level service to actually use it, and it will *open* the port as part of the normal procedures of using the port.)

From the `Xrdp(8)` man page:

> -p, --port
>
> Specify TCP port to listen to. This overrides port setting in xrdp.ini file.

From the `xrdp.ini(5)` man page:

> port=port
>
> Specify TCP port to listen on for incoming connections.  The default for RDP is 3389.

So Xrdp uses the port specified with the `-p` option if that option is used, or the port specified in the `xrdp.ini` configuration file if option `-p` is not used. If neither of them is specified, it uses port 3389, which is the same port Windows uses for the RDP protocol.

Most outgoing connections and any applications that don't specify a local port number for their TCP/UDP sockets will by default get a local port number in the range specified by the `sysctl` setting `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`. In RHEL/CentOS 7, this range defaults to port numbers 32768..60999.

(Each TCP or UDP connection will have both a local and a remote port number: outgoing connections usually only specify the remote port number and let the OS determine the local one, and ports opened for listening for incoming connections normally only specify the local port number.)

You can exclude specific ports and/or port ranges from this automatic allocation using the `sysctl` setting `net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports`. For example, if you need to reserve ports 40000 and 40001 for some particular use, you can do it with:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports=40000,40001
```

This exclusion from automatic allocation will take effect immediately. To make it persistent, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add this line to it:

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports=40000,40001
```

Any program that explicitly specifies (= binds to) a port that has been reserved in this way will still get it as normal; this reservation will only override the automatic allocation of port numbers.

You cannot really do much else; if a regular user process requests a specific port number that is >1023 and is not currently in use by something else, the operating system *will* grant that request. (To use ports in the 0..1023 range, a process must run as `root`, or if a Linux distribution uses more fine-grained privileges, it needs to have the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability.)

However, you may be able to use `iptables` rules to make that port unusable to anything except the specific purpose, depending on what that purpose is. For example, you could restrict incoming/outgoing connections to that port to only those that fit the specific purpose, or use `iptables -m owner --uid-owner <username>` to restrict it to be useful for a specific user only, with a pair of rules like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --sport 3389 -m owner --uid-owner specified-user -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --sport 3389 -j REJECT
```

(The first rule will match the port and the intended user, and will ACCEPT the traffic and end rule processing for it; if that rule did not match, the second rule will match the port only, and will REJECT the outgoing traffic of anyone that is not the intended user of that port.)

This will not necessarily *prevent* other users from trying to use the port, but will make it so that the port will always *fail to connect* for them, so hopefully they will stop trying to use it.